# Google Hangouts with fullscreen screenshare

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

We would like to use Google Hangouts for corporate multi-user communication, mainly for screensharing. The default setting does not support fullscreen mode, the only option is to resize the browser window to fullscreen (F11). Unfortunatelly with this the screen share size is still not big enough.

Is there any way way to use Hangouts in fullscreen mode?

Skype is not an option because the free version does not support multi-user webcam/screenshare conference.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported at the moment.

However, I found [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+KatherineGramann/posts/dT8g4zF5UVm) from a Google employee that involves a little hacking to get it done for On Air Hangouts.  Haven't tried this myself though.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could do this, the quality may not be what you expect. The screenshare is done by sending the screen image into a video stream, rather than trying to send a screen image itself. The video streaming is better tuned to handle actual video from a camera, and is of a resolution (640x360) that is probably far smaller than most screens you'd like to share.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (from [here](http://justingale.com/2013/02/user-tip-zoom-out-to-improve-google-hangout-screen-sharing/)) if you zoom out (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>) when in full-screen mode the screen resolution is shared in higher quality.  Zoom to something like 50%.  I tried recording a screen-sharing video straight to YouTube using this method and it seemed to work.  Don't forget to zoom back out when you're done (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

The following was announced by Google on June 11, 2015:

> For a richer experience when presenting screen-shared content, today
> we’re launching full-view screen sharing for Google Hangouts.
>
> Moving forward, when people using Hangouts present to meeting
> participants in ‘Present to everyone’ mode─or another participant pins
> someone who is screen-sharing─Hangouts participants will see two
> changes to the user interface:
>
> - The screen shared content will use as much visible area of the screen as possible. The thumbnail photos of meeting attendees will
>   overlay the content at the bottom of the screen by default.
> - A new button will be added to the control bar at the top to allow participants to hide the thumbnail photos of meeting attendees as
>   desired.
>
> [image]
>
> Check out the [Help
> Center](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/1660627) for more
> information.

**References**
[Full-view screen sharing for Google Hangouts - Google Apps Update Alerts](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.mx/2015/06/full-view-screen-sharing-for-google.html)